# Delphi DBGrid alternate row colors for all DBGrids in the project

Tags: delphi, delphi-xe, tdbgrid

How can I make all my grids look the same way all over my forms?
I want to implement an alternate row color that must be applied on all grids of my project. Is it possible without adding the same DrawColumnCell event code for every grid?
I want to avoid adding the same code for each of my grids. I have like 30 grids in my project and multiplied by 13 rows of code it just adds a lot of code lines to my project making it "unfriendly".
I am looking for a solution that will only add 13 lines of code to the project, not 390 lines.

My formatting code looks like this (for example):

```
procedure TDBGrid.DBGrid1DrawColumnCell(Sender: TObject;const Rect: TRect;DataCol: Integer;Column: TColumn;State: TGridDrawState) ;
var
   grid : TDBGrid;
   row : integer;
begin
   grid := sender as TDBGrid;
   row := grid.DataSource.DataSet.RecNo;
   if Odd(row) then
     grid.Canvas.Brush.Color := clSilver
   else
     grid.Canvas.Brush.Color := clDkGray;
   grid.DefaultDrawColumnCell(Rect, DataCol, Column, State) ;
end;
```

Probably I would need to extend the DBGrid somehow, but I do not know exactly how nor how to look for a solution for this on google

I tried to hack the DBGRid inside each form like this:

```
type
  TDBGrid = class(DBGrids.TDBGrid)
  protected
    procedure DrawColumnCell(const Rect: TRect; DataCol: Integer;Column: TColumn; State: TGridDrawState); override;
  end;
...
procedure TDBGrid.DrawColumnCell(const Rect: TRect; DataCol: Integer;Column: TColumn; State: TGridDrawState) ;
var
       grid : TDBGrid;
       row : integer;
begin
       row := 2;//grid.DataSource.DataSet.RecNo;
       if Odd(row) then
         Canvas.Brush.Color := clSilver
       else
         Canvas.Brush.Color := clDkGray;
       DefaultDrawColumnCell(Rect, DataCol, Column, State) ;
end;
```

I can do this but I cannot access the sender, so I can access the dataset and know which record to color and which not (odd and even).
And this is a poor approach anyways since I will have to do it on every form, so it's not really a solution

Any ideas?

Thank you

Answer (score 5):

If you put something like this in your datamodule, and assign it to the `OnDrawColumnCell` of every DBGrid, it seems to work (see notes that follow):

```
procedure TDataModule1.DBGrid1DrawColumnCell(Sender: TObject; const Rect: TRect;
  DataCol: Integer; Column: TColumn; State: TGridDrawState);
const
  RowColors: array[Boolean] of TColor = (clSilver, clDkGray);
var
  OddRow: Boolean;
begin
  // Safety check, although it really isn't needed; no other control accepts
  // this event handler definition, AFAIK, so the only way to call it with the
  // wrong Sender type would be to do so in your own code manually. In my own
  // code, I'd simply leave out the check and let the exception happen; if I
  // was stupid enough to do so, I'd want my hand slapped rudely.
  if (Sender is TDBGrid) then
  begin
    OddRow := Odd(TDBGrid(Sender).DataSource.DataSet.RecNo);
    TDBGrid(Sender).Canvas.Brush.Color := RowColors[OddRow];
    TDBGrid(Sender).DefaultDrawColumnCell(Rect, DataCol, Column, State);
  end;
end;
```

A couple of notes:

- First, you should avoid using `TDataSet.RecNo` in the first place, because post-BDE datasets don't typically have this value available. Accessing it (particularly on large or query-based datasets) causes a major performance hit to your application. Of course, not using it means that you can't use this solution. A better solution would be to use a handler for the dataset's BeforeScroll or AfterScroll event that toggled a boolean available to this code instead, and use that instead of the test for `Odd(RecNo)`, or if the dataset is only used for displaying in the DBGrid, use the `TDataSet.Tag` in the `AfterScroll` event to track the row's odd/even state using

  ```
  OddRow := Boolean(DataSet.Tag);
  DataSet.Tag := Ord(not OddRow);
  ```
- Add DBGrids to the uses clause of your datamodule, and manually declare the above event in the `published` section so that it's available to all units that use the datamodule. You can then assign it in the Object Inspector Events tab as usual from those units.
- This does not properly handle the `TGridDrawState` (nor does your initial code). You'll need to add handling for that yourself, as that wasn't what you asked here.
- Depending on which color you want for odd and even rows, you may want to reverse the order of the colors in `RowColors`.
- I prefer the repeated typecasts so that it's clear what the code is doing. If it bothers you, you can simply declare a local variable instead:

  ```
  var
    OddRow: Boolean;
    Grid: TDBGrid;
  begin
    if (Sender is TDBGrid) then
    begin
      Grid := TDBGrid(Sender);
      OddRow := Odd(Grid.DataSource.DataSet.RecNo);
      ...
    end;
  end;
  ```

Answer (score 2):

This works for Delphi XE7

```
type
  TDBGrid=Class(Vcl.DBGrids.TDBGrid)
    procedure WMVScroll(var Message: TWMVScroll); message WM_VSCROLL;
  end;

procedure TDBGrid.WMVScroll(var Message: TWMVScroll);
begin
  Self.Invalidate;
  inherited;
end;

procedure TForm1. DBGrid1MouseWheel(Sender: TObject; Shift: TShiftState;
  WheelDelta: Integer; MousePos: TPoint; var Handled: Boolean);
begin
  if Sender is TDBGrid then
    (Sender as TDBGrid).Invalidate;
end;

procedure TForm1.DBGrid1DrawColumnCell(Sender: TObject; const Rect: TRect;
  DataCol: Integer; Column: TColumn; State: TGridDrawState);
const
  MyRowColors : array[Boolean] of TColor = (clLime, clMoneyGreen);
var
  RowNo  : Integer;
  OddRow : Boolean;
  S      : string;
begin
  if Sender is TDBGrid then begin
    with (Sender as TDBGrid) do  begin
      if (gdSelected in State) then begin
        // Farbe für die Zelle mit dem Focus
        // color of the focused row
        Canvas.Brush.Color := clblue;
      end   
      else  begin
        // count := trunc((Sender as TDBGrid).Height div (Rect.Bottom - Rect.Top));
        // RowNo := (Sender as TDBGrid).Height div Rect.Top;
        RowNo := Rect.Top div (Rect.Bottom - Rect.Top);
        OddRow := Odd(RowNo);
        Canvas.Brush.Color := MyRowColors[OddRow];

        // Font-Farbe immer schwarz
        // font color always black
        Canvas.Font.Color := clBlack;
        Canvas.FillRect(Rect);
        // Denn Text in der Zelle ausgeben
        // manualy output the text
        if Column.Field <> nil then begin
          S := Column.Field.AsString;
          Canvas.TextOut(Rect.Left + 2, Rect.Top + 1, S);
          //  Canvas.TextOut(Rect.Left + 2, Rect.Top + 1, 'Column.Field.AsString');
        end;
      end;
    end 
  end; 
end;
```